# Rodrigues type formula for Chebyshev

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods

I need to show the Rodrigues formula for Chebyshev polynomials i.e $T_n(x)=\dfrac{(-1)^n(1-x^2)^{1/2}}{(2n-1)!!}\dfrac{d^n}{dx^n}[(1-x^2)^{n-1/2}]$ for n=0,1,2,...       So far I have been able to show that
$T_n(x)=2^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^n {{2n}\choose{2k}}(x+1)^{n-k}(x-1)^k $, my step is to use Leibniz Differentiation rule to compute the $n$-derivative in the Rodrigues formula to show it follows from this last equation. Any suggestion in this sep I would appreciate.

Comment: Well, first you may want to write down your definition of Chebyshev polynomials in the question.

Comment: I used the Transcendental formula: $T_n(x)=\dfrac{1}{2}((x+\sqrt[]{x^2-1})^n+(x-\sqrt[]{x^2-1})^n)$ , but I use it to derive $T_n(x)=2^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^n {{2n}\choose{2k}}(x+1)^{n-k}(x-1)^k$

Comment: Hint: can you find a recursive formula of $T_n$ based on the transcendental formula?